# How do I clear Text Input Layout set error upon any change in the input?

Tags: java, android, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

I have tried to use

`textinputlayout.setError(null)`

using TextWatcher, but the error still shows. It only disappears upon returning to the activity after going to another one

Comment: textinputlayout.setError(null) should work fine. Some more code would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Call both `setError(null)` and `setErrorEnabled(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextInputEditText` 's `onFocusChangeListener` and call `textEditInputText.setError(null)` in the listener.

Answer (score 0):

OnTextChange when your text is valid than call only `setErrorEnabled(false)` thats it.